# How to not read the next line if a condition is met?

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline

I'm working on project (C++) that reads a file (.txt) similar to this:

0
40
120
360
440
760
840
1080

I'm using a For Loop with the function getline() to read the file line by line, but in the For Loop I have a condition, and if that condition is met I don't want to read the next line, instead, I want that the pointer that reads the file stays in the same position for the next iteration of the loop. How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that you have described exactly how to do it: if the condition is met, don't call `getline()`.

Comment: But how I do that if my condition is inside the for loop?

Comment: The same way as when the condition is outside the for loop. `if` statements works the same way, whether they're inside some loop, or outside of it.

Comment: So imagine that I have: **for (i = 0; getline (readMyFile, text); i++) { if (condition) { ...}}**. How can I not call **getline()** function?

Comment: The direct way: move it inside the `if` statement and change the loop condition to only check the stream state; or leave out the loop condition entirely, and move the loop termination logic inside the `for` loop (using the `break` statement).

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to read the line using `ifstream`,look at [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) . And then store it into vector or array;
pseudo code for your purpose may look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int array[size];
    ifstream file_num("file.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(condition){
            file_num>>array[i];
        }
   }
        //you can return the index of the position where you want to break and then use it from that index for next iteration;
}
```

Comment: It looks good, the only question is, the size of my file isn't static. But thank you for the answer